# How to delete a row in UITableView manually?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, uitableview

Here's what I've come up with:

```
NSIndexPath *indexPath = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:0 inSection:1]; // my table view has 2 sections
[tableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationTop];
```

Everytime I build and run, it throws the following exception:

> Invalid update: invalid number of rows in section 0.  The number of rows contained in an existing section after the update must be equal to the number of rows contained in that section before the update, plus or minus the number of rows added or removed from that section.

It's a bit confusing. The section is set to 1, yet the exception says it's 0.

Comment: loved your line NSIndexPath *indexPath = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:0 inSection:1];. +1 for you ;)

Answer (score 29, accepted):

I figured it out.

In addition to the aforementioned code, I also need to make changes to the datasource

```
[items removeObjectAtIndex:0];
```

Comment: For anyone who had been receiving the error, like I was, stated in the OP; please be sure to alter your data model `before` altering the UITableView's contents.

Answer (score 6):

```
- (IBAction)deleteCustomCellWithUIButton:(id)sender
{
  NSLog(@"Message From Custom Cell Received");
  NSIndexPath *indexPath = [self.myTableView indexPathForCell:(UITableViewCell *)[[[sender superview] superview] superview]];
  NSUInteger row = [indexPath row];
  [self.myDataArray removeObjectAtIndex:row];
  [self.myTableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:indexPath]  withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
}
```

Comment: I recommend adding `[self.myTableView beginUpdates];` before you start changing. And `[self.myTableView endUpdates];` once you're done.