# How to delete row in TTTableViewController (Three20)

Tags: iphone, three20

The Three20 is great library. It's making the work with tables very easy. But one gap that I  noticed - is deletion of rows, with animation. I spent many hours trying to do this, and this is what I'm doing:

```
// get current index patch
UITableView* table = [super tableView];
NSIndexPath *indexPath = [table indexPathForSelectedRow];

//delete row in data source
TTListDataSource * source = (TTListDataSource *)self.dataSource;
[source.items removeObjectAtIndex:indexPath.row]; 

// delete row from the table, with animation
[table deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
```

After this code runs the error appears: [NSCFArray objectAtIndex:]: index (0) beyond bounds (0)

I'm using the class inherited from the TTTableViewController. And I doesn't implement the DataSourceDelegate or TableViewDelegate because I'm using the Three20 as much as possible. So, this is how I create datasource:

```
for(NSDictionary *album in (NSArray *)albums){

TTTableRightImageItem *item = [TTTableRightImageItem itemWithText:@"name"  
            imageURL:@"image url" 
           defaultImage:nil 
          imageStyle:TTSTYLE(rounded)
           URL:@"url of selector where I actually catch the tap on a row"];
[tableItems addObject:item];
}
self.dataSource = [TTListDataSource dataSourceWithItems:tableItems];
```

I read this article ([article](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1384659/unable-to-delete-rows-in-table-using-three20)) but it doesn't help :(

So, I know that this is very simple for gurus from this site. Can you just give me advanced sample of how to do this

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first thing I spot is that you're deleting a row from the table when the table is not in editing mode.

Comment: ok. it's weighty remark. I've added the line "table.editing = YES;", just after  the line "NSIndexPath *indexPath = [table indexPathForSelectedRow];". The result is the same :(

Comment: The class TTSectionedDataSource would not be sufficient for use in an editable table as it does not implement tableView:commitEditingStyle:forRowAtIndexPath.  Subclass TTSectionedDataSource and implement ableView:commitEditingStyle:forRowAtIndexPath. In this method delete the item, then call didDeleteObject. This method will notify your controller and do the animation.

Comment: Actually I need only to remove the row programmatically, with animation. Like here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/915095/how-to-delete-a-row-in-uitableview-manually , but with Three20.

I noticed that there are "- (void)removeItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath*)indexPath" method in TTSectionedDataSource. But it throwing an error!! Maybe it's a bug in Three20??

Comment: If I'm not mistaken the member items within the TTSectionedDataSource is an array or arrays - one for each section. In your code you are removing the whole array, which will remove all the items in that section. So you should do something like:
 NSArray* section = [source.items objectAtIndex:indexPath.section];
  [section removeObjectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

Comment: hum, it's true. I've modified the source above. But now I see strange behavior. When I run the code above, I see the row deletion, and just after animation completed - application terminates with error "Program received signal:  “EXC_BAD_ACCESS”."

Comment: How many rows are in the section? Is it the only row? Looks like you have a memory problem try turning on NSZombies: http://www.cocoadev.com/index.pl?NSZombieEnabled to see if you're over releasing somewhere.

Comment: yep. it's definitely because of only one row in the table. And it looks like something strange happening with the Sections. Because when I change TTSectionedDataSource to TTListDataSource, everything is starting to work fine! I don't really matter about sections, so it's fine for me to use TTListDataSource. however, I really appreciate that you spent your time helping me :)
Thank you a lot

PS
I've modified the code above so you can see the working version

Answer (score 4):

I also got "EXC_BAD_ACCESS" in `model:didDeleteObject:atIndexPath:` but I got that problem solved.

To delete a row in a TTTableViewController you need to implement `tableView:commitEditingStyle:` in your DataSource implementation like this:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView commitEditingStyle:(UITableViewCellEditingStyle)editingStyle 
        forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    if (editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyleDelete) {
        id object = [[self.items objectAtIndex:indexPath.section] objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

        [self.model didDeleteObject:object atIndexPath:indexPath];
    }
}
```

You also need to implement `tableView:willRemoveObject:atIndexPath:` in your DataSource:

```
- (NSIndexPath*) tableView:(UITableView *)tableView willRemoveObject:(id)object atIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    // delete the object
    [object deleteFromDB];

    // removeItemAtIndexPath returns YES if the section is removed
    if ([self removeItemAtIndexPath:indexPath andSectionIfEmpty:YES]) {
        // remove an index path only to that section
        return [NSIndexPath indexPathWithIndex:indexPath.section];
    } else {
        return indexPath;
    }
}
```

The trick is to change the `NSIndexPath` you return to only contain the section of it gets empty. Then the code in TTTableViewController removes the section instead of the cell.

HTH

Comment: I wonder why you called `[self.model didDeleteObject:object atIndexPath:indexPath];` in the data source's  `tableView:willRemoveObject: atIndexPath:` method. Shouldn't you call `[self.model removeSomeObject:... atIndexPath:indexPath]` and have this object calling `[self didDeleteObject:object  atIndexPath:indexPath]` instead?